# iOS presentViewController is not working right

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

As part of my updating my apps to replace the deprecated presentModalViewController with presentViewController, I did some testing.
What I found was disturbing. Whereas presentModalViewController always works and there is no question about it working, I have found the presentViewController method often will not display my VC at all. There is no animation and it never shows up.
My loadView are called without problems, but the actual view does not appear.

So here is what I am doing:

- User taps a button in my main view controller.
- In the callback for that tap, I create a new view controller and display it as shown above.
- The VC never appears (it is an intermittent problem though) but because this VC begins playing some audio, I know that its loadView was called, which looks like as follows.

My button-pressed callback is as follows:

```
  - (void) buttonTapped: (id) sender {
  VC *vc = [[VC alloc] init];
  [self presentViewController: vc animated:YES completion: nil];
  [vc release];
  }
```

Here is my loadview in the VC class:

```
 - (void) loadView {
 UIView *v = [UIView new];
 self.view = v;
 [v release];
 ... create and addsubview various buttons etc here ...
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: you will need some piece of code...

Comment: Also, did you see any messages printed in the log?

Comment: No, this is not a known problem. Most likely, you're doing something wrong. I've never had any trouble with this method. Show your code.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the controller that calls the function has its view currently displayed (or is a parent to the one currently displayed) and it should work.